# twitterbot/1.0 causing high CPU and Ra

Tags: wordpress, twitter, web-crawler

I don't know why but all days at the same hour I have visits from Twitterbot/1.0 that cause a high resource usage for a minute more or less.

Not so important but I would like to know how to make this not no to crawl. I have Twitter bot enabled in robots.txt cause I need it for sharing articles (Twitter cards) but those visits are not due to sharing, it seems it crawling.

I have tested sharing a card and same ips so it's not a fake not saying "ey I'm Twitter"

Any idea what is happening and how to block this ones and still allow sharing? I have also tried to put a crawl delay but it seems this bot doesnt read this option. In Twitter developer forum nobody answers me about this issue...

If you need a log please let me know and I will paste here this crazy amount of visit from this crawl just in the same minute almost at same hour all days...

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Nginx, you should check [Rate Limitting](https://www.nginx.com/blog/rate-limiting-nginx/).

I am using something like that:

```
geo $limit_key {
    default         '';
    199.59.148.0/22 'twitterbot';
}

limit_req_zone $limit_key zone=req_limit:1m rate=1r/s;

…

location … {
    limit_req zone=req_limit burst=3 delay=3;

    …
}
```

Thus, that zone limits request rate from the Twitterbot IP-range to 1 per second (and up to 3 additional on a burst), then postpones each subsequent request for 3 second, and then responding 503 for each over-limit request.
Add the `limit_req` directive in the required locations.

This method can be used to limit request rate from known IPs – just add CIDR or IP to the `$limit_key`-map.
Smart bots understand the 503 status code and retry failed requests later.

By default, Nginx writes the limit to the `error.log`:
`grep 'limiting requests' error.log`

```
2021/11/03 05:31:28 [error] 27594#27594: *4623504 limiting requests, excess: 3.196 by zone "req_limit", client: 199.59.150.182, server: example.com, request: "GET / HTTP/2.0", host: "example.com"
```

Details in the [documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_limit_req_module.html).